# How to delete series line chart in c#

Tags: c#, charts

I make a chart line collect points. When I draw 2 points (20,20) and (40,40) it works, but when drawing the point (30,0) in the middle of my graph into a triangle.
What do I need to fix it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Line chart that I want:
[image]
Current error I am encountering:
[image]

I am code:

```
<i>
private void btnConfirm_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ChartControl point = new ChartControl();
            float s_question_true = 0;
            int percent;
            int dexibel = 0;
            float trunggian;
            CheckEdit[] _checkBoxes;
            _checkBoxes = new CheckEdit[] { checkEdit1, checkEdit2, checkEdit3, checkEdit4, checkEdit5, checkEdit6, checkEdit7, checkEdit8, checkEdit9, checkEdit10 };
            for (int i = 0; i < _checkBoxes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_checkBoxes[i].CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    s_question_true++;
                    Console.WriteLine("gia tri cua s_question_true = {0}", s_question_true);
                }
            }
            trunggian = (float)(s_question_true / 10);
            percent = Convert.ToInt32(trunggian * 100);
            dexibel = Convert.ToInt32(lbDecibel.Text);
            //DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Bạn có muốn kết thúc bài Test không?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
                if (check_play == true)
                {
                    if (btnOption.Caption == "Kiểm tra")
                    {
                        series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(dexibel, percent));
                        series1.View.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        this.chartControl1.Series.Add(series1);
                        ((LineSeriesView)series1.View).MarkerVisibility = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
                        ((LineSeriesView)series1.View).LineMarkerOptions.Kind = MarkerKind.Circle;
                    }
```

}

}

Comment: You need to post the code you're using to generate the charts.

Comment: You need to sort your values by x. Line charts work like that.

Comment: Best use points.InsertAt or order the DataPoints, which is a bit tricky after the fact..

Comment: i use insertPoint after use series.changeView, this not change :(